# how to click on link text selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, webdriver, click

i tried to click on link text but no work. Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Bán chạy"}

please help me.
My code:
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Bán chạy').click()

https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone

**[image: strong text]**

[image]

Comment: this is element: <div class="shopee-sort-by-options__option">Bán chạy</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by below way

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Bán chạy')]")))
element.click()
```

***OR***

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[normalize-space(),'Bán chạy']")))
    element.click()
```

Comment: it take an error  
Message: element not interactable

Comment: Can you add the full HTML for the element ?

Comment: <div class="shopee-sort-by-options__option">Bán chạy</div>  
This is full element

Comment: This does not look full HTML you can add the picuture of above nodes too. I updated the answer, please check, In case you face the issue than check is there any `iframe`

Comment: Have you tried the updated answer ?

Comment: not yet, there is a problem that webdriver can not load the page, although it loaded nomarly on my edge. So i will update ASAP

Comment: there is no problem with internet or even edge browser but when i excute the script, webdriver open edge and can not load the page

Answer (score 0):

A link text is only used to identify the hyperlinks on a web page. It can be determined with the help of an anchor tag `<a>`. In order to create the hyperlinks on a web page, you can use anchor tags followed by the link text.

Here this element is inside a `<div>` tag so you can't select this element using linktext locator you can use XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR like following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Bán chạy')]").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Bán chạy'')]").click()

Comment: Why are you using `elements`  ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).